# Is there a difference between measuring the resistance using a multimeter ohm function and using the voltage / current relation?

Tags: resistance, multimeter

I need to measure the electrical resistivity of a concrete sample following the procedure described in ASTM C-1760.

The procedure requires a 60V DC potential to be applied across the concrete sample (cylinder with 10cm diameter and 10cm length) and the current measured to obtain the bulk resistivity of the sample.

The problem is that I don't have a power supply capable of delivering 60V.

I was wondering if a regular multimeter can produce the same result using the ohm function. The expected sample resistivity should range 50 - 500 Ohm.m

Comment: If the resistivity of the material is linear, then you probably can use multimeter, but that would be considered as a deviation from the standard procedure and will not be compliant (unless explicitly permitted)

Comment: Try it, see what kind of readings you get.  Little 9V battery won't put out the same current as a 60V supply.  You can get a 60V supply for around $25 USD. 60V/50 ohm indicates  1.2A of current needed.  https://www.amazon.com/Supply%EF%BC%88SMPS%EF%BC%89-220VAC-DC60V-Transformer-Monitoring-Industrial/dp/B079D9KTF7/ref=sr_1_9?keywords=60v+power+supply&qid=1579713882&sr=8-9

Comment: @CrossRoads Its not 50\$\Omega\$, it is 50\$\Omega\cdot\text{m}\$....not resistance but resistivity.

Comment: @Oldfart But the **area** of the sample is not 1m\$^2\$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ohm function on your multimeter will use the voltage-current relation to determine the resistance of a sample. It will either apply a voltage and measure the current delivered, or force a current and measure the voltage required to deliver it.

But it will almost certainly not use a voltage as high as 60 V, so it won't meet the needs of your test.

Probably the ASTM spec requires a 60 V source to provide a repeatable test method that allows for breakdown of some of the thin layers of oxide material within the concrete, but not others. The higher voltage used may also be needed to accurately measure currents due to ionic transport within the never completely cured concrete.

Therefore I'd expect you need to use an actual 60 V source to achieve a compliant measurement.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not.  Most DVMs use low voltage and are designed around *typical* electrical components and wire.

Items made from *other materials* may not conduct until a certain voltage threshold is reached.  Also, without enough voltage the material may not conduct uniformly, which will also skew your results.

Comment: "Probably"..."most"..."may not"..."may not"?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a perfect, aka linear, resistor, and components called 'resistors' that you can buy are more or less 'perfect', then there will be no significant difference between what you measure with a DVM on the ohms range, and what you compute having measured voltage and current.

If on the other hand what you want to measure the resistance of is something complicated, with perhaps non-linear resistance, then the way you measure it is indeed relevant. Something damp like concrete will react to current flow with internal chemical reactions which will modify the current flow, this is called polarisation. The grains may be coated with thin insulating films that break down at particular voltages. If you want to measure a sample to ASTM C-1760, then you need to use the procedure that ASTM C-1760 defines.